# Angular2 - How to have multiple route-outlet for one route

Tags: angular, dart

I have an app that share a main layout with multiple routes. When I'm in the Listing route, I want to display a side bar.

```
@Component(
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '''
<div class="main">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
  <h3>Sidebar</h3>
  <!-- I want to put a SideBarComponent here when I'm in the Listing route -->
</div>
''',
    directives: const [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES])
@RouteConfig(const [
  const Route(
      path: '/listing',
      name: 'Listing',
      component: ListingComponent, // Add SideBarComponent
      useAsDefault: true),
])
class AppComponent {}

@Component(selector: 'listing', template: '<div>List</div>')
class ListingComponent {}

@Component(selector: 'side-bar', template: '<div>Side bar</div>')
class SideBarComponent {}
```

How should I specify multiple components in the RouteConfig?

Comment: Which version are you using of angular2?

Comment: The Dart version ;-) As far as I know aux routes aren't well supported in Dart yet.